Why does FatFs f_getfree function return an incorrect value?
I would like to get free memory on USB drive (64GB, FAT32) with FatFs library. Here is part of my code:
DWORD fre_clust, fre_sect;
uint64_t free_memory;

res_file = f_mount(&fs, "0:", 1);
res_file = f_getfree("0:", &fre_clust, &fs);
fre_sect = fre_clust * fs.csize;
free_memory = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)fre_sect*(uint64_t)fs.ssize)/1048576;//MB

The problem is that f_getfree() always returns same value, even if data size is changed. Also I would like to say that res_file has return value FR_OK in both cases and Iam able to write data on USB drive with FatFs.
Does anyone know what Iam doing wrong?
Thank you for your response.

"The problem is that f_getfree() always returns same value, even if data size is changed." What are the values? Which way and how much do you change the data?

Hi, thank you for your help, I have already solved the problem. Reformatting the usb drive fixed this issue.
